# How to access a state variable inside useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I am using a firebase SMS authentication login, but my isssue is i can not access functional state variable inside useEffect() hook

how can i access this state variable inside a useEffect hook,

```
 const [number, setNumber] = useState(null);
 useEffect(() => {
    NumberRef.current = number;
 } , [number])

 useEffect( () => {
 auth().onAuthStateChanged( (user) => {
    if (user) {

       console.log(number);
    } 
    else 
    {
       auth().signOut().then(() => console.log('User signed out!'));
    }
});
}, []);
```

when i was trying accessing **number** state variable inside useEffect hook. it's show me a error like **undefined**

Plz help me to solve this problem

Comment: How is `number` initialized?

Comment: yes sir it's initialized after a sign in

Comment: its's declared const [number, setNumber] = useState(null); and the error is "number" is "undefined"

Comment: shouldn't you use NumberRef.current? it must be null in the first render not undefined